# Events are not showing in Angular6 PRIMENG scheduler

Tags: angular, fullcalendar, angular6, primeng

I would like to use Primeng Schedule component in my project https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/schedule

I have tried using events(updated same in following code) in the schedule and trying to retrieve events from schedule. But, not able to retrieve the same

Code:
in component.ts:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.header = {
      left: 'prev,next',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    };

    this.eventstest = [
      { title: 'All Day Event', start: '2018-08-07' },
      { title: 'Long Event', start: '2018-08-10', end: '2018-08-11' },
      { title: 'Repeating Event', start: '2018-08-11T16:00:00' },
      { title: 'Repeating Event', start: '2018-08-16T16:00:00' },
      { title: 'Conference', start: '2018-08-12', end: '2018-08-13' }
    ];
  }
}
```

HTML Code:

```
<p-schedule [events]="events" [header]="header" [height]="'parent'" [nowIndicator]="true"></p-schedule>
```

Following Version and environment I am using for my project:

- Angular CLI: 6.0.8
- Node: 8.11.3
- OS: win32 ia32
- Angular: 6.0.9

Any help in this regard is highly appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is some progress I could do, by creating method for loadevent(). loadEvents(event) {
    this.events = [ { title: 'All Day Event', description: 'testing', start: '2018-08-07' },
    { title: 'Doctor visit', start: '2018-08-01T09:00:00', end: '2018-08-01T10:30:00' },
    { title: 'Long test', start: '2018-02-05', end: '2018-02-05' },
    { title: 'Patiet Consultant', start: '2018-08-11T16:00:00' },
    { title: 'Repeating Event', start: '2018-08-16T16:00:00' },
    { title: 'Conference', start: '2018-08-01', end: '2018-08-03' }
]
However, I am not able to retrieve the events.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lot of experiments, I could successful in retrieving the events. The following code is used for the same.

```
 eventClicked(event) {

    if (event.title) {
      alert('Clicked ' + event.title + '.\n' + 'Will open ' + event.url + ' in a new tab');
      return false;
    } else {
      alert('Clicked ! ' + event.calEvent.title);
    }
  }
```